# kong header base rate limiting

Tags: rate-limiting, kong, kong-plugin

I want to apply rate limiting by header.

if X-yunus-api-key == fasdasd231jnde32e32e , apply rate limit.

Does Kong has this feature ?

```
--header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
--header 'X-yunus-api-key: fasdasd231jnde32e32e' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{ }'
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to apply rate limiting by header.
> if X-yunus-api-key == fasdasd231jnde32e32e , apply rate limit.

Setting `config.limit_by` to `header` and specify `config.header_name` to `X-yunus-api-key` in [rate-limiting plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/rate-limiting/) should be enough for your use case.

If you also want to validate the consumer. Using the [key-auth plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/key-auth/) and setting credentials for consumers is another valid option

Comment: Actually want to apply rate limit by header value. This is for rate limit by header. in this case, if header change, rate limit will be disable.  For example; X-yunus-api-key has 3 value, first: fasdasd231jnde32e32e, second : 123uıqwd1, third: 214eu23ınufr. I want to apply rate limit if X-yunus-api-key = fasdasd231jnde32e32e. I dont want to apply rate limit second and third value. @Ponsakorn30214

Comment: If you want to validate the header value, the second option I provided will be suitable for you
1. Set `config.key_names` in key-auth plugin to validate the header key.
2. Create a consumer
3. Create key credential for said consumer
example can be seen in key-auth plugin link I provided